# Pasting into separate workbook must I save the workbook to get the path first

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large macro I am amending for my purpose. The writer of the macro was more skilled than me. The macro at present runs formulas on data gathered from websites and other spreadsheets.

All I want to do is to have "Red Flagged" ranges copied and pasted into a the same new workbook. Can this be done without having to save the new work book?

Here was my initial idea:

```
   Sub CreateNewWB()
    With Application
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
        .Workbooks.Add
        .Sheets(1).Name = "Late"
    End With
    Set ptrToLate = Application.ActiveSheet.FullName
   ' MsgBox ("This workbook has name" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name)
    'MsgBox ("This workbook has Full name" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
   ' MsgBox ("This workbook has path name" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)
   ' MsgBox ("This workbook has Code name" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.CodeName)
    End Sub
```

At the very top of the VBA code I had put

```
Dim ptrToLate as String
```

with the intentions of being able to copy and paste using the new workbooks name as a destination, but I get the error: "Object doesnt support this property or method"

1) Is there a way to append to an unsaved workbook?

2)presently the codename of the new workbook is "thisWorkbook" this confuses me because I thought that thisworkbook referred to the workbook the macros itself is written in

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set the new workbook to an object and then you can reference it without the path. The variable wrkb will now reference your destination new workbook.

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
'Adding New Workbook
Set wrkb = Workbooks.Add(1) 'this creates anew workbook with only 1 sheet
wrkb.Sheets(1).Name = "Late"

Workbook("Red Flagged.xlsx").Sheets("redflagged").Range("A1:D2").Copy wrkb.Sheets("Late").Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

To the question in the title: *VBA when pasting into separate workbook must I save the workbook to get the path first?*

The answer is **YES**

If you open a new workbook and write this in the VBEditor, you would see that there would an empty `MsgBox`. If you save it and then run the code again, the path would be shown:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path
End Sub
```